# Update a template in TFS 2015 not working for the web interface

Tags: tfs-2015

I have updated a template of a Work Item in TFS 2015 called User Story. I simply created a rule on a field to set a default value.

To default the field I did the following : 
On visual Studio, on the Main Menu, click on Tools / Process Editor / Work Item Types / Open WIT from server.
Browse to the Work Item (User Story in this exemple) Then click OK.
Double click on the field to edit. On the Rules tab. Add a new rule : DEFAULT.  From: Value and Value: My Text here.

I can see the change on the user story when I use Visual Studio but not on the Web Portal.
Is there anything that I need to do for the web portal to get get this change?

Could that be a bug ?

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in my TFS 2015.4, and got correct behavior.

Here are my steps for your reference:

1. Add a new field and make it available on work item form.
2. Add a DEFAUL rule, the XML looks like:

   `<FieldDefinition name="test" refname="test.test" type="String">
     <DEFAULT from="value" value="mytext" />
    </FieldDefinition>`
3. Check this custom field in VS:

[image]

4. Check this custom field on web portal:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying it. I am wondering if there is more than one way to set the default value for a field. On the web portal, I noticed that if I erase the default value (that I assume if a TFS default Value that I am trying to update) and save, then the default value that I set thru the rule shows up like I would expect. But I would expect it when the form opens, not after I make a change.

Comment: In my example, the default value just shows up when I create a new UserStory, not need to make a change. How did you set the default value? Could you try my example, or share your steps here?